# Configuration System Failed to Initialize

Tags: c#, app-config

I'm writing a small program in C# visual Studio 2010, using 2.0 .Net framework.  I'm trying to read values from an App.config file.  My config file looks like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="MyApp.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup> 
  </configSections>
  <applicationSettings>
    <add key="Path" value ="C:\Program Files\MyApp\bin\" />
    <add key="UserName" value="UserName" />
    <add key="Pword" value="Password" />
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

Then in my code at:

```
path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Path"];
```

I get a runtime error "Configuration System Failed to Initialize".
From what I've read the configSection has to be first in the file, but I've done this and still get the error.

Comment: Also please post the code accessing the settings.

Comment: Inner exception is: "Unrecognized configuration section applicationSettings/add."

Answer (score 9):

Put `<configSections>` before `<appSettings>` and it should work

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
...
</configSections>
<appSettings>
...
</appSettings>
</configurations>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've worked it out, the tag `applicationSettings` should be called `appSettings`.  And I can then get rid of the `sectionGroup` tags leaving just this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Path" value="C:\Program Files\MyApp\bin\" />
    <add key="UserName" value="username" />
    <add key="Pword" value="password" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be way off on this one, you should escape your backslashes.
I.e. `C:\Program Files\MyApp\bin\` becomes `C:\\Program Files\\MyApp\\bin\\`

Comment: I don't believe so - not in a config file.

Comment: Not entirely certain of it either tbh

Answer (score 0):

Might be The Configuration file has been corrupted and is unreadable.Delete the Existing .Config File and Create A new With Same Name and Settings .

by using same practice I have resolve same problem many time .

```
         <add key="Path" value ="C:\\Program Files\\MyApp\bin\\" />
```

If you want to use Multiple path in your Code then Use [Combine Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx)

Comment: The backslashes don't need to be doubled in a config file - and I certainly *wouldn't* just routinely delete and recreate the config file. I'd try to get to the bottom of what's wrong first, paying attention to the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Please, check below image...
You need to add your key into  tag.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do know this is a very late addition but just thought if it would help someone else why not. 
When it comes to using "applicationSettings" note that you cannot as of today you cannot mix the "settings" of "applicationSettings" and "add" of "appSettings" in other words you cant have

```
<setting name="Name You choose" serializeAs="String">
        <value>True</value>
      </setting>
```

and

```
<add key="Name You choose" value="1000" />
```

in the same App.config file.